# Downvote - require comment

Tags: feature-request

I've seen a perfectly reasonable answer, others' as well as my own, where I see a downvote, but no comment to substantiate it.

Just thinking out loud, would it make sense that a downvote attempt causes a comment dialog box to appear and the comment is required to enter the vote. On a different stackexchange board, I don't recall the exact topic, but walked away thinking "who downvotes cheesecake?"

On this board, obviously, a factually incorrect answer should get a downvote, but I frequently see it for nothing I can find.

EDIT - OK. How about instead of a comment, there are choices as with a close vote. Say (a) factually incorrect, (b) doesn't answer question as asked, (c) (something else?)

Comment: I was involved in a similar discussion at [Ask Different](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/downvoting-etiquette-with-or-without-making-a-comment) but got downvoted for my position that commenting on one's downvote should be expected etiquette.

Answer (score 7):

[Requiring comments for downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) has been discussed on MSO and shot down.  I guess there is a pop-up suggesting a comment for users with less then 2k rep.  However, requiring a comment is problematic.  There is no guarantee that it will result in useful comments.

Comment: Thanks. I searched here, but not the bigger site. I read the thread you linked to, and understand the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Some users think the downvote says it all, but usually I think it says "I'm lazy" more than anything else.  Perhaps: "I'm having a bad day, and you get to suffer as a result today, just because I can."

Comment: That's a bit pessimistic.  When I downvote and don't leave a comment, it's because I don't want to get into an argument, but at the same time, I don't want the answer standing out as *appearing* correct to users who don't have the information to understand the problems with the answer.  After all, a downvote is just that - one vote down.  It doesn't veto, delete, or otherwise permanently damage the answer (especially because low-rep users can't even see that it was voted down).

Comment: If the net vote count is negative, then any user can see that the answer was voted down.  That, and if arguments will occur, then it might point to a problem with the question itself rather than the answer.

Comment: You're right, of course, I was thinking of already-voted-up questions. Personally, I rarely vote down from 0 unless it's *really bad*. (BTW, I was probably thinking of already-voted up questions because the OP is JoeTaxpayer. Let's be honest, all his answers get upvotes :))

Comment: Yeah, JT knows a thing or two about this stuff. ;)